# How to create an endpoint without creating sub endpoints?

Tags: url-rewriting, endpoints

I'm trying to create a new endpoint using `add_rewrite_endpoint()`. Here's my code:

```
// Add query var.
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'my-endpoint';
    return $vars;
} );

// Add endpoint.
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my-endpoint', EP_AUTHORS );
} );
```

I can now visit example.com/author/my-endpoint which is great but "sub" endpoints also seem to work. For example:

- example.com/author/my-endpoint/random
- example.com/author/my-endpoint/anything-here

How can I create my endpoint **without** also creating these "sub" endpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rewrite rule added by:

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my-endpoint', EP_AUTHORS );
```

is

```
author/([^/]+)/my-endpoint(/(.*))?/?$

=>

index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&my-endpoint=$matches[3]
```

so it assumes anything after e.g. `/author/henrywright/my-endpoint/...`.

You can try instead to replace it with `add_rewrite_rule()` e.g.

```
add_rewrite_rule( 
    '^author/([^/]+)/my-endpoint/?$', 
    'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&my-endpoint=1', 
    'top'
);
```

Comment: `add_rewrite_rule()` seems far more flexible. Thanks for sharing this solution.